# Attribute dropdown not showing on product page Magento1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-view

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1 , I have faced problem on product details page(view.phtml file).

In this not show color attribute dropdown. Only empty dropdown show.

I have set up all setting in admin but not showing color dropdown. I have used another attribute like size than same problem showing.

Please help me this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution this- Use this code we can get attribute option.

```
<?php 
              if ($_product->getData('type_id') == "configurable")
                {
                    //get the configurable data from the product
                    $config = $_product->getTypeInstance(true);
                    //loop through the attributes
                    foreach($config->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product) as $attributes)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="select_number">
                            <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $attributes["label"]; ?></label>
                                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $attributes['attribute_id'] ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $attributes['attribute_id'] ?>">
                                        <?php

                                        foreach($attributes["values"] as $values)
                                        {
                                            echo "<option value=".$values["value_index"].">".$values["label"]."</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
```